# How can I get a function declared in an eval() function to run in setinterval?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

`const code = eval(document.getElementById("codearea").value); setInterval(code, 10);`
I want to access a function declared inside of the eval kind of like:
`setInterval(code.examplefunc,10)`

I tried to access the function just by the name, but because i am using a module script, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const str = `obj={examplefunc:function (){return 111}}`
         const code = eval(str);
         console.log(code.examplefunc())
```